# deploy and run java application on jboss

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

I am using eclipse juno with jboss 7.1.0.
I am able to deploy my application but when i am running it on server it is showing resource not available.Please can anyone tell me what are the steps to deploy an application and run it on server successfully.

Comment: Have you checked that there's no exception in the JBoss log?

Comment: there are no exceptions

Comment: The log must at least show an entry saying that your app was deployed. Did you get that line?

Comment: ya its coming.....Deployed "WebProj.war"

Comment: ok, what URL do you use to access to your application? Are you trying to access through Eclipse internal browser or a real browser like Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/WebProj....through both browser..bt not working